# How to calculate the QuickPath Interconnect (QPI) bandwidth?

Tags: central-processing-unit, bandwidth, intel, numa, smp

For Xeon E5-2697 v2, Intel [lists](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/75283/intel-xeon-processor-e5-2697-v2-30m-cache-2-70-ghz.html):

> Bus Speed = 8 GT/s
>
> # of QPI Links = 2

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_QuickPath_Interconnect), one must know the QPI frequency and link width to calculate the QPI bandwidth, but these don't seem to be listed here. How to calculate it then?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an authoritative-looking [paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20170000291/downloads/20170000291.pdf) (NASA- and SGI-affiliated authors) that explains it:

The total bandwidth is 8 GT/s * 2 links * 2 bytes per transfer = 32 GB/s in each direction, for a total of 64 GB/s.